How to make this URL pattern acceptable in ASP.NET Core?
I am working in an ASP.NET Core project with Razor pages and I am trying to make this URL pattern
/{clientName}/Forms/{page}

acceptable to route. You should know I'm using Razor Pages NOT MVC.

clientName is any string
Forms is area
page is any page in forms area

I did something similar in MVC, but it didn't work for me in this case.
Now I want to get clientName in OnGet method. How can I do this?
What are the changes I should add to Program.cs?

Hello, have you tried the suggestion offered by Mike? Did you able to make any progress on this?

yes, it works. thank you.

Change the name of the page parameter to something like pageName. page is a reserved word in Razor Pages.

let me explain. I want the route to be like this https://localhost:7161/xyz/Forms/CreateApp. I want to get to all Pages in Forms Area, so I did {page} in the route

Yes, but page is a reserved word and cannot be used as a parameter name in Razor Pages. If you change it to /{clientName}/Forms/{pageName} "CreateApp" will be bound to the pageName route value.
